# How can I connect to Gnome 3 with a Windows VNC client?

Tags: gnome3, vnc

I used to be able to connect to my Gnome 3 desktop from a Windows machine with a VNC client.  But after an upgrade (on the Linux side) a while ago, it quit working.  When I attempt to connect, all I can get is a message saying "No matching security types" or "No supported authentication methods!" (depending on which client I try).

In Gnome 3, I've turned on Screen Sharing under Settings > Sharing.  Under that, I have Remote View on, Remote Control on, Approve All Connections on, Require Password off.  I'm running Arch Linux with vino 3.8.1.

On the Windows side, I've tried TigerVNC 1.0.1 & 1.2.0 and UltraVNC 1.0.9.6.2.

How can I get this working?

Comment: Is your firewall disabled and/or configured to allow VNC traffic through to the server?

Comment: @slm, I don't believe it's a firewall issue, because I don't think you get that error unless the client has successfully opened a connection to the server and asked it what authentication methods it supports.

Comment: Can you connect to the VNC server using a VNC client from something other than a Windows computer? Just trying to eliminate another variable. Also what version of Windows are we dealing with?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is actually a known and [currently open bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=981984). However, there is a very easy workaround; just issue the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
```

You will now be able to connect with most vnc viewers.

Comment: After setting this do I need to restart vino-server or anything? I have just tried this and get the same error.

Comment: This is a user level setting, so, if you're still have trouble after changing it, make sure you didn't run it with `sudo`.

Comment: This is bad advice. Anyone on the network (wifi or ethernet) can sniff your traffic, and intercept keystrokes including passwords.

Comment: `require-encryption false` really bad idea ! you are disabling the encryption so unless you are on a Ethernet (and ethernet only !!)  or on a WiFi in a cottage located in the middle of nowhere then yes then you can use this

Answer (score 7):

Here are some other possible solutions:

1. Disable Vino encryption, and then setup an SSH tunnel
2. Use a VNC client compatible with Vino's encryption (TLC): Android: bVNC Free, Windows: [Java Turbo VNC client](https://turbovnc.org/Main/HomePage), Linux: vinagre
3. Use a different VNC server, such as tigervnc or x11vnc
4. Use a different VNC server, such as tightvnc, with a different desktop manager, such as MATE, Xfce, LXDE, etc.

Even 2.5 years later, this is still an issue with Fedora, Redhat, and Debian systems... Basically, Gnome 3 does a 3D graphics driver check when starting up gnome-session, which causes it to crash vncserver when NOT using Vino; so, use a different desktop manager. Alternatively, you use Vino, and then are required to either use Type 18 TLS and a handful of compatible VNC viewers, or turn off encryption and have all you traffic be easily sniffed; so, turn off encryption and use an SSH tunnel.

It's a convoluted problem that requires the coordination of multiple groups of developers to solve, and very little progress has been made.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question covers all alternative methods and suggestions how to connect to Gnome throught VNC if built-in desktop sharing does not work: [Enable remote desktop for Gnome from command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73041/enable-remote-desktop-for-gnome-from-command-line/73103)